# Remove CRLF from a string in an XML tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

The following is an excerpt from one of the XML files that I am learning to parse using Python and beautifulsoup.

```
<xml>
    <codeblock>
    <syntax>configure</syntax>
    <syntax>      context
    local</syntax>
    <syntax>           interface <variable>interface_name</variable></syntax>
    <syntax>                ip
    address <variable>ip_address</variable> <variable>subnet_mask</variable></syntax>
    <syntax>                exit</syntax>
    <syntax>           server
    ftpd</syntax>
    <syntax>           ssh
    key <variable>data</variable>
    length <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
    <syntax>           ssh
    key <variable>data</variable>
    length <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
    <syntax>           ssh
    key <variable>data</variable>
    length <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
</codeblock>
</xml>
```

I would like some advice on how to remove the CRLF from the string within the <syntax> phrase to have <syntax> and </syntax> in the same line, while retaining the indent at the beginning of the string.

Please note that the <codeblock> tag appears in multiple levels in the actual XML file.

I tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(opxmlFilename),'xml')
for tag in soup.find_all('syntax'):
        tag.string = str(tag.text).replace("\n", " ")
```

While this removes the '\n' between the <syntax> tag, it also removes all the child tags (<variable>).

Appreciate some inputs on this.

I am a technical writer trying to learn XML parsing with python for basic automation activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice gentleman from the python IRC page helped with the following solution using `NavigableString` that works flawlessly:

```
xml_string="""
    <xml>
        <codeblock>
            <syntax>configure</syntax>
            <syntax>      context
            local</syntax>
            <syntax>           interface <variable>interface_name</variable></syntax>
            <syntax>                ip
            address <variable>ip_address</variable> <variable>subnet_mask</variable></syntax>
            <syntax>                exit</syntax>
            <syntax>           server
            ftpd</syntax>
            <syntax>           ssh
            key <variable>data</variable>
            length <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
            <syntax>           ssh
            key <variable>data</variable>
            length <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
            <syntax>           ssh
            key <variable>data</variable>
            length <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
        </codeblock>
    </xml>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string,"xml")
for syntax in soup.find_all('syntax'):
    new_tag = soup.new_tag('syntax')
    for child in syntax.contents:
        if "\n" in child:
            new_tag.append(child.replace("\n", " "))
        else:
            new_tag.append(child)
    syntax.replace_with(new_tag)

print soup
```

Output:

```
<xml>
<codeblock>
<syntax>configure</syntax>
<syntax>      context            local</syntax>
<syntax>           interface </syntax>
<syntax>                ip address <variable>ip_address</variable>                <variable>subnet_mask</variable></syntax>
<syntax>                exit</syntax>
<syntax>           server ftpd</syntax>
<syntax>           ssh key <variable>data</variable> <variable>octets</variable>    </syntax>
<syntax>           ssh key <variable>data</variable> <variable>octets</variable>    </syntax>
<syntax>           ssh key <variable>data</variable> <variable>octets</variable></syntax>
</codeblock>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question completely, but wouldn't this give you what you're looking for. If not, please run it and see what's wrong and we can try to figure that out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

for tag in soup.findAll('syntax'):
    print tag.text.strip()
```

Comment: tag.text.strip() does not seem to remove the carriage return within the string. However, tag.text.replace("\n"," ") seems to do the trick. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.